# openshift gear using 100% inodes

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm trying to git push my app up to Openshift.  I get the following error:

```
Stopping Node.js application...
Warning: Gear 575efb722d5271dec00000f4 is using 100.0% of inodes allowed
Failed to execute: 'control stop' for /var/lib/openshift/575efb722d5271dec00000f4/nodej
```

I don't know what this means.  What are inodes?  I found no help on Openshift help.  I checked the space quota for my gear and I'm at 60%.  What does this mean?

If this is any clue, I recently downloaded a few babel files so I can start to use async/await in my node app.

Anybody?

Comment: An issue with reaching limit on inodes is more to do with the number of files, not the cumulative size of the files. Check the number of files you have and that you haven't created a large number of temporary files from your application which haven't been cleaned up.

Comment: You can try using `rhc app-tidy <app_name>` on OpenShift Online v2 to clean temporary files, or do that manually as described [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html#_resolving_disk_space_issues) to reduce the number of files,